# show existing selection for dynamic checkbox

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am creating checkboxes dynamically and want to show the existing selection or want to check them dynamically.this is the code to create checkboxes

```
    private void Role()
    {
        SystemUserDal dal = new SystemUserDal();
        var roles = dal.GetRolesList();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<Guid, string> r in roles)
        {

            CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
            chk.ID = r.Value;
            chk.Text = r.Value;
            rolepanel.Controls.Add(chk);
        }
    }
```

i have

```
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            SystemUserDal dal = new SystemUserDal();
            var userID = Guid.Parse(Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString());
            var user = dal.getSystemUserByID(userID);
            if (user != null)
            {
                Role();
                var role = user.Roles;


                textuserid.Text = user.UserId.ToString();
```

user.Roles has all the roles a particular user is assigned. how can i mark the dynamically created checkboxes?

I tried this but still dint work as role has more than one value in it

```
    private void Role(string role)
    {
        SystemUserDal dal = new SystemUserDal();
        var userId = Guid.Parse(Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString());
        var roles = dal.GetRolesList(userId);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<Guid, string> r in roles)
        {

            CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
            chk.ID = r.Value;
            chk.Text = r.Value;
            if (role == r.Value)
            {
                chk.Checked = true;

            } rolepanel.Controls.Add(chk);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably rewrite your `Roles()` function

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<Guid, string> r in roles)
{

    CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
    chk.ID = r.Value;
    chk.Text = r.Value;

    if(User.IsInRole(r.Value))
       chk.Checked = true;

    rolepanel.Controls.Add(chk);
}
```

A better alternative is to use `<asp:CheckBoxList />` control

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="RolesList" runat="server">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Code-behind

```
for (int i = 0; i < RolesList.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (User.IsInRole(RolesList.Items[i].Value))
       RolesList.Items[i].Selected = true;
}
```

Comment: thanks codingbiz I tried this but user gets populated after this check box is created so throwing null error

Comment: role contains more than one value and both roles list and roles are created dynamically how can i check if role contains r.value?

Comment: Thank you codingbiz the following worked   foreach (KeyValuePair<Guid, string> r in roles)
            {
                 CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
                chk.ID = r.Value;
                chk.Text = r.Value;
                if (role.Contains(r.Value))
                {
                    chk.Checked = true;

                } rolepanel.Controls.Add(chk);